# python modules installed with pip not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, asciimatics

I searched for a lot of information but nothing helped me.
So, basically every module installed in the python37\lib\site-packages is not importing.
because this problem doesn't appear in PyCharm I just forgot about it and worked there, but now I need to use asciimatics that doesn't work good in PyCharm and I tried to solve it.

here is sys.path
C:\Program Files\Python37\python37.zip
C:\Program Files\Python37\DLLs
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\Python37
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages

also here is a pip -V
pip 20.1.1 from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

as I get it, everything should work but doesn't :'(
I would really appreciate the help thanks.

EDIT:
I should have used python  instead of py .

I want to die just because I spent so much time on trying things but at the end its something that simple. (I thought about it thanks to the comment)

Comment: The problem You seem to describe might be due to different Python interpreter being used than the one which installs the packages.

Comment: do you know a way to check that? and if its true how to fix it?

Comment: I know how to check it while using VS Code for sure.
But when using different IDE/Editor Your best bet would be to go over to environment variables and see what paths are exposed as env variables. Also I would try to go into PyCharm or the editor options and check what kind of interpreter is default for them and if it is the same that You can access through the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment yet:

I would recommend you using a venv or anaconda (https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Windows/). When creating a project in Pycharm you can select it. It will then install all packages inside the venv and it should work